# How to Achieve Gmail's Compose Email to field

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Kindly help.
I will like to achieve this :
[image: similar to Gmail's to field]

I create a CodePen here :

```
<a href="http://codepen.io/babafemiwebmaster/pen/vgOjyd">CodePen Link </a>
=======================================
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.recs = [];
    $scope.clss = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "lastname": "Primary I",
            "alias": 'J2'
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "lastname": "JSS 11",
            "alias": 'J1'

        }
    ];
    $scope.stff = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "firstname": "Babafemi",
            "lastname": "Adigun",
            "isactive": true
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "firstname": "Owner",
            "lastname": "Staff",
            "isactive": true
        }
    ]
    $scope.all = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.clss, function (value, key) {
            $scope.recs.push(value.lastname);
        });
        angular.forEach($scope.stff, function (value, key) {
            $scope.recs.push(value.lastname);

        });


    }
});
</script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='MainController'>
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rec">Recipients:</label>

        <div class="input-group" ng-init=all()>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap">   </i></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rec" ng- model="smsbody.recipient"
                   typeahead="lastname for lastname in recs | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="from">From</label>
        <input type="title" class="form-control" id="from" placeholder="Your  Name (11 xters)" maxlength=""
               ng-model="smsbody.from"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message {{maxLength}}</label>
        <span>Characters left: {{256 - message.length}}</span>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" ng-maxlength="maxLength"  id="message"
                  ng-model="smsbody.message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sendSms()">::Send::</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I have achieved the autocomplete using angular's typeahead feature.
However, I need the selected user to be added to the text box same way Gmail is doing theirs with option to remove the selected item from the textbox.
Same thing stackoverflow is using to add tags
I appreciate all inputs, and the time spent reading this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
<a href="https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips">Angular Material</a>
```

Thanks all the same.